# facebook JS API Login open in new tab instead of popup in IE 7-8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, fbconnect, facebook-login, fbjs

I have a website with facebook connect and a facebook page tab in witch the user must login to facebook.

I use the JS API and it open a popup to let the user connect.

It work fine everywhere but in ie 7 and 8.

instead of opening in a popup it open in a new tab. The user can log in but after it stay open and redirect to a blank page (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request).

The login was successful and if the page is refreshed the user is logged in, but I need it be a popup and close itself after and do a callback so I can refresh the page like in other browser.

anyone have an idea on how to fix this, tried everything i could find and nothing work.

a part of my code : 
$`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                          appId   : '<cfoutput>#appId#</cfoutput>',
                          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                          oauth   : true, // OAuth 2.0
                          status  : true, // check login status
                          xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
                          channelUrl: 'http://192.168.1.96/gocoupons/OngletFacebook/channelUrl.cfm' //custom channel
                    });
                };

                (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                }(document));

                /*(function() {
                    var e = document.createElement('script');
                    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                    e.async = true;
                    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                }());*/
                function login() {
                    //$.cookie('fbsr_<cfoutput>#appId#</cfoutput>',null);
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'email,user_checkins'});
                }
                function addToPage() {
                    FB.ui({method: 'pagetab'}, function(response){
                        $('#pageid').val(JSON.stringify(response));
                        $('#formAjoutPage').submit();
                    });
                }
            </script>
```

`

Comment: just found out that the same problem is also on http://www.netvibes.com if you try to login with facebook connect..

Comment: and on one of the official exemple : 
https://apps.facebook.com/runwithfriends/